# Why does this style effect all the tags even though I closed it, when I use printf

Tags: php, css

I'm currently studing PHP and I tried to color the `<h1>` tag. But the previous style influenced the `<h1>` tag.

This is my code:

```
<?php
echo "<span style='color:#$lets'>hello world!</span";

echo "<Br />
<Br />";


printf("<h1 stlye='color:#%X%X%X'>hello world! again.</h1>",200,250,100);

?>
```

Comment: Your span is not closed properly - it is missing the closing bracket.

Comment: Because `stlye` isn't a valid HTML attribute. Make it `style` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't closed your span tag and you have a typo, should be style instead of stlye.

```
<?php
echo "<span style='color:#$lets'>hello world!</span>";

echo "<Br />
<Br />";


printf("<h1 style='color:#%X%X%X'>hello world! again.</h1>",200,250,100);

?>
```

Comment: This is correct. But in order to make it more obvious, I suggest you update the answer to explain what's the change that you made, and why the OP's code wasn't working :)